# Which version of hbase am I using?

Tags: hbase, version

How to see the `version` of `hbase` I am using?
Could you give the command?

Comment: "hbase version" from the command line

Answer (score 7):

`hbase version` command in command line interface gives the `version` of `hbase` that is being in use.

Below are the two snapshot from `Cloudera` and `Hortonworks` distribution respectively. The highlighted portion gives the version:

- Cloudera
  [image]
- Hortonworks
  [image]